# mysql update column value from another table

Tags: mysql

post

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| tid | uid | pid |
+-----+-----+-----+
|   1 |   1 |   1 |
|   2 |   1 |   2 |
|   3 |   1 |   3 |
|   3 |   2 |   4 |
|   4 |   1 |   5 |
...
+-----+-----+-----+
```

thread

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| tid | lastpid | lastuid |
+-----+---------+---------+
|   1 |       0 |       0 |
|   2 |       0 |       0 |
|   3 |       0 |       0 |
|   4 |       0 |       0 |
...
+-----+---------+---------+
```

I hope the thread's result is:

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| tid | lastpid | lastuid |
+-----+---------+---------+
|   1 |       1 |       1 |
|   2 |       1 |       2 |
|   3 |       2 |       4 |
...
+-----+---------+---------+
```

How do you finish it with one statement?
Post's tid = thead's tid, and post max(pid)'s pid,uid is thead's value.

I want to get pid and uid from post max(pid) that post.tid eq thread.tid.
And set the pid,uid to replace thread 's lastpid and lastuid.

---

According to the best answer, we rewrote it to solve this problem:

`UPDATE thread t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tid, uid AS last_uid, pid AS last_pid
    FROM post
    WHERE pid IN (SELECT max(pid) FROM post GROUP BY tid)
) p
    ON t.tid = p.tid
SET
    t.lastuid = p.last_uid,
    t.lastpid = p.last_pid;`

Comment: Can you please explain what you're asking?

Comment: I think you switched the data in the `lastpid` and `lastuid` columns.

Comment: My english is poor. But the problem has been solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try an update join:

```
UPDATE thread t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tid, MAX(uid) AS max_uid, MAX(pid) AS max_pid
    FROM post
    GROUP BY tid
) p
    ON t.tid = p.tid
SET
    t.lastuid = p.max_pid,
    t.lastpid = p.max_uid;
```

If you instead just want to do a select, then the above can be slightly modified, basically just by replacing `UPDATE...` with `SELECT`.

Note that it appears that `lastuid` and `lastpid` have been swapped in your expected output.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: Sorry. There seems to be something wrong. I need lastpid's uid and lastpid's pid.

Comment: @skiy Just swap the assignments in the `SET` clause then, q.v. my updated answer.  I guess it wasn't a typo.